# Checking whether a String contains a number value in Java

Tags: java

How can I write a method to find whether a given string contains a number? The method should return true if the string contains a number and false otherwise.

Answer (score 87):

```
if(str.matches(".*\\d.*")){
   // contains a number
} else{
   // does not contain a number
}
```

Previous suggested solution, which does not work, but brought back because of @Eng.Fouad's request/suggestion.

#### Not working suggested solution

```
String strWithNumber = "This string has a 1 number";
String strWithoutNumber = "This string does not have a number";

System.out.println(strWithNumber.contains("\d"));
System.out.println(strWithoutNumber.contains("\d"));
```

#### Working solution

```
String strWithNumber = "This string has a 1 number";
if(strWithNumber.matches(".*\\d.*")){
    System.out.println("'"+strWithNumber+"' contains digit");
} else{
    System.out.println("'"+strWithNumber+"' does not contain a digit");
}

String strWithoutNumber = "This string does not have a number";
if(strWithoutNumber.matches(".*\\d.*")){
    System.out.println("'"+strWithoutNumber+"' contains digit");
} else{
    System.out.println("'"+strWithoutNumber+"' does not contain a digit");
}
```

Output

```
'This string has a 1 number' contains digit
'This string does not have a number' does not contain a digit
```

Comment: Why did you replace the previous solution with this? :\ You should keep the old one and append the new one

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: Because it doesn't work. This one will always work! This was my code if you still need to try it: `strWithNumber.contains("\d")`.

Comment: If you're trying to use regular expressions there it doesn't work (you would have to escape that backslash because `\d` is is not a valid escape character in Java). Even if you use `\\d` it will return false for both because `String.contains()` matches `CharSequence` and doesn't check for RegEx.

Comment: @alexcoco: exactly why I removed it!

Comment: See my answer for a RegEx solution. You can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 30):

Using a loop -

```
public static boolean containsDigit(final String aString)
{
    if (aString != null && !aString.isEmpty())
    {
        for (char c : aString.toCharArray())
        {
            if (Character.isDigit(c))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Using a stream -

```
public static boolean containsDigit(final String aString)
{
    return aString != null && !aString.isEmpty() &&
            aString.chars().anyMatch(Character::isDigit);
}
```

Comment: This seems more elegant that using `.matches()`. I'd like to know which is faster though. `matches()` seems to create Pattern and Matcher objects on the bg, does that have a performance impact ? How is a regex compiled and compared against a string, that I'm not sure of. A test would be nice :)

Comment: my bets are, that this method would be faster, as it gets into the job right away. I have no idea how a pattern is matched and can't think of doing a match without brute-forcing the given string. So I'd say this is likely to be faster as it's more _direct_. Run @kaj's solution too, fun stuff :D

Comment: @Ivan, I think that it is faster, I did some (very unreliable and unprofessional) tests and it looks like the character array is fastest and Scanner is the slowest.

Comment: assigning a variable in the if statement is a bit unusual and causes a compiler warning in my IDE.  You could remove the containsDigit flag and replace "break" with "return true".

Answer (score 6):

Shef's answer doesn't compile for me. It looks like he's using RegEx in `String.contains()`. If you want to use RegEx use this:

```
String strWithNumber = "This string has a 1 number";
String strWithoutNumber = "This string has a number";

System.out.println(strWithNumber.matches(".*\\d.*"));
System.out.println(strWithoutNumber.matches(".*\\d.*"));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regex to find out if the String contains a number. Take a look at the `matches()` method.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you try to write a function based on `Integer.parseInt(String obj)` ? The function could accept as parameter your String object, and then tokenize the String and use `Integer.parseInt(String obj)` to extract the number from the "lucky" substring...

[Javadoc of Integer.parseInt(String obj)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: This would be the quickest way, but it is not proper software engineering. I mean, one should check if the string is a number is a number doing operations ON the String, and not mapping the number retrieval through Exception firing.

Comment: Just the overhead of catching exceptions and handling them is silly. Exceptions are for *exceptional* cases, not for checking if Strings contain digits.

Comment: That is exacyly what I said above..

Answer (score 3):

Looks like people like doing spoonfeeding, so I have decided to post the worst solution to an easy task:

```
public static boolean isNumber(String s) throws Exception {
    boolean result = false;
    byte[] bytes = s.getBytes("ASCII");
    int tmp, i = bytes.length;
    while (i >0  && (result = ((tmp = bytes[--i] - '0') >= 0) && tmp <= 9));
    return result;
}
```

About the worst code I could imagine, but there might be other people here who can come up with even worse solutions.

Hm, containsNumber is worse:

```
public static boolean containsNumber(String s) throws Exception {
    boolean result = false;
    byte[] bytes = s.getBytes("ASCII");
    int tmp, i = bytes.length;
    while (i >0  && (true | (result |= ((tmp = bytes[--i] - '0') >= 0) && tmp <= 9)));
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 try{
      Integer.parseInt(string);
      return true;
}catch (Exception  e){
      return false;
}
```

or you can do it himself:

```
 for ( int i = 0; i < string.length; ++i ) {
      if ( !( string[i] >= '0' || string[i] <= '9' ) )
           return false;
 }
 return true;
```

Of course is also function isDigit

Answer (score -3):

Another possible solution is to use a `Scanner` object like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputString);  
if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {  
  return true;
}
else {
  return false
}
```

Of course, if you are looking for a `double`, use `hasNextDouble()` method (see: [Scanner javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html))

Comment: If Java.util provides us a pattern scanner like Scanner, why should not we use it???