# Java check if a string contains int:int

Tags: java, regex

I need to check if a string contains number:number, and I can't find how

```
if(args[0] contains int:int){
    code
}
```

Tried

```
if(args[0].matches("(\d{1,})[:{1}](\d{1,})")){
  code
}
```

but it tells me

```
Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )
```

Comment: Perhaps a little research on your own? A quick google search on "if a string contains a number" should suffice

Comment: Does anyone even know about Google anymore?

Comment: [Can we see your attempts to solve this problem?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking if a string contains a number or not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344867/checking-if-a-string-contains-a-number-or-not) - side note: not exact duplicate but plenty to make an attempt off of.

Comment: He's got an extra character in there, so it's close but I think perhaps slightly different.

Comment: I checked on google, but my problem was the ":"

Comment: @davidp027 this is a perfect time to learn something about regex. Look at some other answers, try some stuff out. You will fail, then fail again then eventually succeed. This is when you learn something. Not to mention this is a very simple regex to write.

Comment: I tried (\d)[:](\d*), works on online regex testers but in my code it says: "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the simple regex is `"\\d+:\\d+"`.
This can be for the middle of the string or the entire string if
that is all you will allow.

I think match validates the entire string.
If you need match, and it can be in the middle, something like this might work.
`"^(?s).*\\d+:\\d+.*$"` and the  `^$` anchors may be implicit.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (args[0].matches(".*\\d+:\\d+.*")) {
    ...
```

OK, this is now correct. I'll leave it here in case it's useful for anyone.

note: This solution assumes args[0] will not contain newlines.

Comment: He said contains, not matches.  Depending on his spec, you might have to allow for extra characters at the beginning and end of that regex.

Comment: Also add extra slash to escape existsent ones.

Comment: Test your answer before you post it.

Comment: @markspace Sorry I'm not particularly familiar with java specifics. I was under the impression that this wasn't needed if I left off ^ and $.

Comment: I've changed my code to use contains instead of matches. As @markspace correctly points out, matches will try to match the entire string.

Comment: @Pshemo I didn't realise I had to double escape the backslash when adding the code. I didn't have a java environment handy to test when I posted the answer, hence the minor mixup with matches vs contains.

Comment: "*I believe this is now the correct answer*" don't base you answer on believes, but simply test it. You don't need installed IDE, there are many online ones like http://ideone.com/.

Comment: BTW `contains` doesn't use regex, and `matches` checks if entire string matches regex, not if string contains some part which can be matched by regex. Anyway since there is already correct answer posted here consider deleting your answer if you are bothered with downvote (your will get back reputation lost here after some time).

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks for the tip about ideone.com. I've corrected the answer now. I was closest with my original answer. There is already another accepted answer, however it's unnecessarily complex. This is the simplest correct answer, so I'll leave it in case it's useful to anyone.

Comment: `(?i)` is not unnecessary. It represents `dotall` flag which lets `.` match any character (normally `.` represents any character except line separators). It is useful in case of string containing multiple lines.